# Regarding got to command in tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to print character from the next line:

say :

when this variable dum=183 exists in file , then print the very next charater from next line.

Note : I am using tcl

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started.

The typical idioms for working with a file one line at a time are:

1) linewise reading:

```
set f [open thefile.txt]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    # work with the line of text in "line"
}
close $f
```

2) block reading with line splitting:

```
set f [open thefile.txt]
set text [read $f]
close $f
set lines [split [string trim $text] \n]
foreach line $lines {
    # work with the line of text in "line"
}
```

This can be simplified by using a package:

```
package require fileutil
::fileutil::foreachLine line thefile.txt {
    # work with the line of text in "line"
}
```

Another way is to search and extract using a regular expression. This is the *worst* method as it is inflexible and very likely to be buggy in use.

```
set f [open thefile.txt]
set text [read $f]
close $f
# this regular expression is an example
if {[regexp {\ydum\y[^\n]*.(.)} $text -> thecharacter]} {
    # the character you wanted should be in "thecharacter"
}
```

Documentation:
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help !